# MS DOS XCOPY Command - Action if 0 File Copied

Tags: dos, xcopy

I have created a simple XCOPY command to copy a file from source to target location.  This command executes based on a certain event.

XCOPY Source*.FLT Dest\

If the source file does not exist, or the destination folder is missing, it gives a message: "0 Files copied".  Is it possible to prompt a warning message, like a Windows dialog box, if no files are copied?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ErrorLevel` set when the command fails.

```
0 = No Issue/Success
2 = Abort
4 = File Not Found
...
```

Just check if the ErrorLevel is anything other than 0.

```
if ErrorLevel 1 echo Error
```

See `if /?` for more details.

Note that the ErrorLevel if comparison is evaluated as follows `if ErrorLevel >= Number then`.